# Bulk Insert multiple record into mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, insert, bulkinsert

How to insert records in below format in mongoDB, as well how to insert from java, i want to insert more than one record at a time.

Jar file used : mongo-java-driver-3.3.0.jar

Document of a collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5873sdsd"),
    "macId" : "1", 
    "keys" : [     
        "item1", 
        "item2", 
        "item3", 
        "item4"
    ],         
    "timekey" : "timestamp", 
    "macKey" : "macId"  
}
```

Comment: Please specify how you are trying to insert - i.e. paste the fragment of your code where you call MongoDB API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the answer below for inserting record from java.

```
Document documents = new Document();
        documents.put("dummyVal", "MId from step 4"); 
        documents.put("timekey", "timestamp"); 
        documents.put("macKey", "dummyVal"); 
        List<String> litItem = new ArrayList<String>();
        litItem.add("setting1");
        litItem.add("setting2");
        documents.put("keys", litItem); // picked keys from page 4
        documents.put("macKey", "dummyVal"); 
        Document documents1 = new Document();
        documents1.put("dummyVal", "MId from step 4"); 
        documents1.put("timekey", "timestamp");
        documents1.put("macKey", "dummyVal"); 
        List<String> litItem1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        litItem1.add("setting1");
        litItem1.add("setting2");
        documents1.put("keys", litItem); // picked keys from page 4
        documents1.put("macKey", "dummyVal"); 
        docList.add(documents1);
dbCollection.insertMany(docList);
```

Example to insert record in mongoDB:

```
 db.getCollection('Dummy').insert(
       { dummyVal: "dummyVal" },
{macKey :'dummyVal'},
       { $push: { keys: { $each: [ 'setting1', 'setting1'] } } }
    )
```